# Remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula - Crystal Reports

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, formula

I have the below formula that is doing basic maths:

```
//Calculate the monetary variance.
numberVar monVariance := {SC01BY00.SC01053} - {SC01BY00.SC01052};

if Not({SC01BY00.SC01053}= 0) Then
    //Calculate the percentage variance.
    numberVar percVariance := monVariance / {SC01BY00.SC01053} * 100;
    //Output percentage variance to the screen.
    percVariance;
Else
    'cannot divide by zero'
```

However, I am receiving the error on the last Else clause and am not sure why.

**Update:**

I seem to have fixed the error. It was my misunderstanding of the crystal syntax. Essentially I can put `( )` around the innards of the `if-statement` to avoid ambiguity, e.g:

```
//Calculate the monetary variance.
numberVar monVariance := {SC01BY00.SC01053} - {SC01BY00.SC01052};

if Not({SC01BY00.SC01053}= 0) Then
    (//Calculate the percentage variance.
    numberVar percVariance := monVariance / {SC01BY00.SC01053} * 100;
    //Output percentage variance to the screen.
    percVariance;)
Else
    'cannot divide by zero'
```

Comment: Why has this post received a downvote? I believe it to be a constructive question which provides help to future users.

Comment: Your formula must evaluate to ONLY numerical values or ONLY string values... you cannot mix and match. In your case, you're trying to output the `perVariance` numerical value or the string 'cannot divide by zero'.

Answer (score 0):

You are following `Crystal syntax` as `formula language`. In Crystal syntax `//` is used for comments whereas your else block is using `'` to denote a comment which is `Basic syntax`

Change `'cannot divide by zero'` to `//cannot divide by zero'` or remove your comment

And, is your `Else` block empty or you are returning something (0 or anything else)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The 'cannot divide by zero' isn't a comment, it is a phrase which is printed out to the screen if the else clause runs....I thought this at first but found out I can use both double and single quotes to denote a printed phrase.